# Is the constant group scheme for $\mathbb{Z}$ affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

Is the constant group scheme for $\mathbb{Z}$ affine?
It is said no in Gille's notes "INTRODUCTION  TO  REDUCTIVE GROUP  SCHEMES  OVER  RINGS" 3.1,  but I don't see why!

Comment: Affine schemes are quasicompact. Is this quasicompact?